# Moving boolean in and out of Python

Tags: python, numba

I'm implementing some numba code following [this](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/interval-example.html#boxing-and-unboxing) example. The example uses floats but my value should be a boolean.

I thought bool_to_bool should return a bool but my code is throwing me the following error

```
TypeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
Invalid store of i8* to i1 in <data.preprocess.numba.MyObj.MyObjModel object at 0x7fbb3f22e7f0> (trying to write member #0)
```

which looks to me that it's converting to i8*. Here's that method

```
from numba.extending import unbox, NativeValue
@unbox(MyObj)
def unbox_my_obj(typ, obj, c):
    flip_sign_obj = c.pyapi.object_getattr_string(obj,"flip_sign")
    my_obj = cgutils.create_struct_proxy(typ)(c.context,c.builder)
    tmp = c.pyapi.bool_from_bool(flip_sign_obj)
    my_obj.flip_sign = c.pyapi.bool_from_bool(flip_sign_obj)
    c.pyapi.decref(flip_sign_obj)
    is_error = cgutils.is_not_null(c.builder, c.pyapi.err_occurred())
    return NativeValue(my_obj._getvalue(), is_error=is_error)
```

I think the only other code that'll be useful is when I declare what type flip_sign is:

```
from numba.extending import type_callable
@type_callable(MyObj)
def type_my_obj(context):
    def typer(flip_sign):
        if isinstance(flip_sign, types.b1):
            return my_obj_type
    return typer
```